# Testing a simple has many association through a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations

To wrap up a exercise I'm working on, I'm trying to test an association through a join table. What I'd like to do is to test the association that Artists have many collections through Art Pieces and Collections have many Artists through Art Pieces. Below is my code:

```
context 'associations' do

let(:artist){ Artist.create(first_name: "Daniel", last_name: "Rubio", 
              email: 'drubs@email.com', birthplace: 'Mexico', 
              style: 'Contemporary') }

let(:art_piece) { ArtPiece.new(date_of_creation: DateTime.parse('2012-3-13'),    
                  placement_date_of_sale: DateTime.parse('2014-8-13'), 
                  cost: 250, medium: 'sculpture', availability: true, artist_id: 
                  artist.id, customer_id: customer.id, 
                  collection_id: collection.id)}

let(:customer) { Customer.create(first_name: 'Carmen', last_name: 'Dent', email:  
                'cdent@email.com', no_of_purchases: 10, amount_spent: 100000) }

let(:collection) { Collection.create(name: 'Romanticism') }

it 'has many collections through art pieces' do
  expect(artist).to respond_to(:collections)
  art_piece.save!
  expect(artist.collections).to eql(collection)
end

end
```

Now I'm positive my associations are setup correctly on my validations:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :art_pieces
  has_many :artists, through: :art_pieces
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates_presence_of :style
  validates_presence_of :birthplace

  has_many :art_pieces
  has_many :collections, through: :art_pieces
end
```

I followed activerecord's guidelines and it makes sense to me. The only two things that I think is happening is either A. I have a syntax error somewhere or B. my variables are not being chained properly. Any insight?

Below is the error message I get:

```
1) Artist associations has many collections through art pieces
 Failure/Error: expect(artist.collections).to eql(collection)

   expected: #<Collection id: 20, name: "Romanticism", created_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42", updated_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42">
        got: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Collection id: 20, name: "Romanticism", created_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42", updated_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42">]>

   (compared using eql?)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -#<Collection id: 20, name: "Romanticism", created_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42", updated_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42">
   +[#<Collection id: 20, name: "Romanticism", created_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42", updated_at: "2014-04-06 16:57:42">]
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: I changed the respond to part to :collections because that was the method I was calling but then I got this. Do you know what it means?

Answer (score 1):

`artist.collection` returns array-like `Relation`, while you test it to return single `ActiveRecord` object. You should have:

```
expect(artist.collections).to eql([collection])
```

in your test.

Comment: Hey Marek, that line of code still didn't work for me, but I dabbled around and I got my test to pass using this line instead. expect(artist.collections).to include(collection)

Comment: Does the .include(collection) make sense to use?

Comment: @DanRubio yes, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    expect(artist.collections).to eql(collection)
```

to

```
    expect(artist.collections).to eql([collection])
```

Currently your rspec is expecting a single collection object but what your query returns is an array like object with a single element in it. Changing the expectation to a list of your collection should do the trick.

Comment: As I commented above for Marek, that line of code didn't work for me but expect(artist.collections).to include(collection) did. It makes sense that it should be an array when I think about it but to no avail. Thanks for your help though.